# German quotation marks in the bibliography along with syntax highlighting

Tags: minted, csquotes

Let's begin with the MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{lit.bib}
% \usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
Text \cite{Beta2016}
\begin{minted}{js}
    var x;
\end{minted}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Here is the file lit.bib:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@MastersThesis{Beta2016,
    author = {Alpha Beta},
    title = {This is a long title to show off quotes!!},
    institution = {Some institution},
    year = {2016},
    owner = {me},
    timestamp = {2016.01.01},
}
```

My problem is that I get the following error message, after I uncomment the `csquotes`-line:

```
LaTeX Warning: Command \@parboxrestore has changed. Check if current package is valid.
```

What I want is german quotation marks in the bibliography and syntax highlighted source code. Is this just something I'm doing wrong or a package incompatibility?

Comment: Does changing the loading order help?

Comment: Actually I have the following working order now: `biblatex` -> `minted` -> `csquotes`
Is there any obvious reason for that behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look to the following MWE (with current MikTeX 2.9):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@MastersThesis{Beta2016,
    author = {Alpha Beta},
    title = {This is a long title to show off quotes!!},
    institution = {Some institution},
    year = {2016},
    owner = {me},
    timestamp = {2016.01.01},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

 \usepackage{minted}% <================================ no warning \@parboxrestore
\usepackage[autostyle, german=quotes]{csquotes} % <=====================
%\usepackage{minted}% <================================= warning \@parboxrestore
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} % <=======================================
%\usepackage{minted}% <================================= warning \@parboxrestore


\begin{document}
Text \cite{Beta2016}

\begin{minted}{js}
    var x;
\end{minted}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I have added the three positions for calling `minted` and noted in the comments if I got a warning or not.  The uncommented call causes no warning on my system.

It compiles with no error and only one warning, resulting in my usage of package `filecontents` to have one compiling MWE including `bib` file and `tex` code).  The the marked changes with `<============`.

As the warning tolds you package `csquotes` changes a command that `minted` needs in other form.  Otherwise `csquotes` has no problem to handle the changed version from `minted`.  At last theese things are the reasons that some packages **have** to be called before others ...

Best would be that both packages adds a hint for the order of call of both packages ...

Sorry for the delay. I first had to bring `minted` to run on my system.

Comment: Well, the order of `csquotes` and `biblatex` doesn't matter in my case. The error only appears if `minted` is loaded after `csquotes`...

Comment: I realized that I was unclear in my comments at the question. I'm sorry for the confusion!

Comment: TeXLive2016. Didn't think about that... But what I thought about was that I've installed this on Win7, 64bit. Looks like Windows is not to blame in this case :)